# Is three halves a fraction?

Tags: fractions

Is three halves (3/2) a fraction?

I understand there may be a more accurate name for this kind of number (improper fraction?) which would be interesting to know. But that isn't what I'm after me, I don't really care if it belongs to a subset or other-set of numbers. I desire to know if it (3/2) can be called a fraction.

Hopefully there is a defintive answer for this rather than mere opinion.

Comment: yes, yes it is.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29
it does not matter if it is proper or improper, it is still a fraction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $3/2$ is a fraction. Any number of the form $$\frac{a}{b}$$ given that $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers, i.e. integers, is called a fraction. The more significant thing about the number $3/2$ is that it is not an integer. It is a rational number, and a rational number is a number of the form as described above.

Comment: Also note that in the form $a/b$, $b$ cannot be equal to $0$.